# Different hashes while pulling from hub and pushing to registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Please see the attached image. I can see different layer hashes and different final image hash while pulling from Docker hub and while pushing it back to my local registry. But, once its pushed to registry, I can see the same layers that I saw during docker pull from hub (I saw these layer details from manifest file on my registry). Why are there different hashes, what exactly is happening here?

[image]

Comment: Probable solution: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1814